# Are the full set of valid arguments for rte_eal_init documented anywhere?

Tags: dpdk

The [dpdk documentation](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__eal_8h.html#a5c3f4dddc25e38c5a186ecd8a69260e3) indicates that the `rte_eal_init` takes arguments `argc` and `argv`, but there does not appear to be any documentation about options that this function considers valid, or what their meanings are.

The [source code](http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/common/eal_common_options.c) lists the options, but doesn't actually explain what each option means.

Is there some place where these options are documented, and their implications for dpdk made clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no single place describing all possible options. Some basic options are described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/build_sample_apps.html#running-a-sample-application).

The most comprehensive list of EAL command line options could be found in [Testpmd User Guide](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html).

For some options, like `vdev` the description could be found inside the PMD's documentation. For example, here is the description of `vdev` options for [libpcap and ring PMDs](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/pcap_ring.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-h` or `--help` option with e.g. one of the DPDK example programs lists all options found in the source (from what I could tell). It also prints a short summary of what each option does. Better than nothing or looking around in the source, but for details and especially `--vdev`, Andriy's answer still stands.

Also, just to make sure because the [API reference](https://doc.dpdk.org/api-23.03/rte__eal_8h.html#a5c3f4dddc25e38c5a186ecd8a69260e3) doesn't explicitly say it at the moment: `rte_eal_init()` is supposed to get its arguments from the `argc` and `argv` arguments of your `main()` function as seen in the example programs.

Answer (score 0):

One place where most of them seem to be documented is https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html